# How can I level this concrete floor so I can install laminate?

Tags: basement, laminate-floor, level, self-leveling-concrete

I did a rough sketch up of what I'm working with in Google Sketchup. I'm laying laminate flooring in my basement living room and have all of the necessary preparations *(Plastic layer and padding)* My question is on the leveling of the flooring. The small circle in the image below is about a 4sqft diameter circle that is not level with the rest of the floor. Images below of the level doing a cross section from middle of the circle to the outside *The images are somewhat hard to see, 1st the bubble is all the way to the right and the second all the way to the left*. Now seeing that this section is raised, a self leveling product would have to be applied to the whole floor to level this out. My thoughts were to smash the raised area down with a sledge hammer and then use a patching product to level it out. DIY What is the best method for me to level this out

[image: Floor Plan]

[image: Level cross section 1]

[image: Level cross section 2]

---

Thanks to @HerrBag solution I was able to level the spot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like taking small crowns out of concrete floors with diamond cup wheel attached to an angle grinder... Need a shop vac and a masked helper.  You may be able to rent both.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can hire someone to grind down the floor. I had this done in my house. It only took a few hours for the worker to remove a lot of material. He used a large diamond grinder that looked like a floor polisher.

It was noisy and dusty. We sealed off the room from the rest of the house. That really helped keep the mess under control.